# adb plugin has device but no inspect

Tags: android, adb, galaxy

have followed every post to find the solution to this problem. Am using Chrome adb plugin to debug on device, a Samsung Galaxy 3. Inspect can see device but there is no "inspect" hyperlink ?????

- Device Debugging Enabled
- can see 1 device on the adb plugin icon
- when I select Inspect Device I see the Samsung 3 device GT-I9300 with it's hash but no inspect link
- have updated the Samsung ADB usb drivers
- have tried Chrome Canary

What else do I have to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem today with my Samsung Galaxy 3 whilst trying to debug a web app in Chrome.  I found that updating Chrome on the device to the latest version fixed this for me.

Comment: Updating the Device Chrome helps debugging Chrome browser based UI but for native debugging need to use the link below if the Android version is less than Android 4.4 (KitKat) 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556409/webview-setwebcontentsdebuggingenabledfalse-but-i-am-able-to-debug-the-code-af